# Is there a way to do a "filter", "if" function across multiple columns to only pull information based on certain criteria and headers?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, worksheet-function, google-sheets-custom-function, google-sheets-filter

I do not know how to explain this perfectly without a picture so please take a look at the image before reading.

[image: FIG 1.]

I am trying to filter the data in Fig 1 (Above). based on the headers and then if the numbered column within that header is not 0 or blank. However, I also need the data from column A to be included in this filter.

For example, Take a look at the header "Bike" in column H. I want to be able to filter the data from only column H and column I because its within the "Boat" header. Then, I also need the blank cells and cells with 0 to not be included in the filter.

In the end it should look like Fig. 2 (Below) after it is filtered. I have tried doing filter if, just filter, etc. and still have not been able to figure it out. If I have to change my format as well let me know.

[image: FIG 2.]

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit per OP's [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/139069/is-there-a-way-to-do-a-filter-if-function-across-multiple-columns-to-only-p/139072?noredirect=1#comment127538_139072)**
>   *(This works great if the rows have no spaces in them but my data does have extra blank rows in between the rows of data as well.)*

```
=IFNA(QUERY({A3:I11},"select Col1, Col"&MATCH(B16,A2:I2,0)&", Col"&MATCH(B16,A2:I2,0)+1&" 
                     where Col"&MATCH(B16,A2:I2,0)&" !=0 and Col1 is not null"),"missing")
```

No problem. Using the above formula you can target and **filter each and every column** in the query. Keep any or all of them according to your needs.

---

You would need the use of the **[`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)** function.

```
=QUERY({A4:A8,D4:E8},"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col2 !=0")
```

[image: Query non-consecutive columns]

Using a "helper" cell e.g. `B11` try the following for a more dynamic result:

```
=IFNA(QUERY({A3:I7},"select Col1, Col"&MATCH(B10,A2:I2,0)&", Col3 
                     where Col"&MATCH(B10,A2:I2,0)&" !=0"),"missing")
```

**To completely automate the process**, using `Data validation`, create a drop-down on cell `B11`, set criteria `List from a range` and pick the headers (`B2:I2`).

[image: Query non-consecutive columns based on headers drop-down list]

Functions used:

- [**`MATCH`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)
- [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [**`IFNA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: This works great if the rows have no spaces in them but my data does have extra blank rows in between the rows of data as well. I know it may seem as though those blank rows are not needed in the initial fig. 1, but they are. However, when I do the formula you gave me it also brings over the blank rows, which I do not need as shown in fig. 2. Do you know of any way to fix this?Thank you so much again!

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: One more question. So what if there are blanks and 0's in the number columns instead of just 0's? @marikamitsos

Comment: What have you tried? Check and try to read how the query is structured and what we did with the other columns. If still in trouble let me know.